# Jquery: code works, but is ugly

Tags: javascript, jquery, code-cleanup

```
var ProdWidth = Math.abs(parseInt(Product.css('width')))
+ Math.abs(parseInt(Product.css('marginLeft')))
+ Math.abs(parseInt(Product.css('marginRight')))
+ Math.abs(parseInt(Product.css('paddingLeft')))
+ Math.abs(parseInt(Product.css('paddingRight')));
```

This works for coming up with the total width of an element including padding and margins, but its stupid. How should I be doing it?

Comment: looks like you've asked a few questions on Stack Overflow, but haven't marked any of them as answered. If an answer, solves your problem you should *accept* that answer by clicking on the green check mark next to the answer. For more information checkout How to ask a question in the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I didn't see the check but I will be sure to do that from now on.

Comment: no problem it's often missed by new users. Like everything on Stack Overflow you get reputation for good behavior. For each question you marked as answered you'll earn 2 reputation points. Happy Programming!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [`outerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) property. It gets the width of the element and its padding, border, etc.

Setting its first argument to `true` will include the margins.

```
var ProdWidth = Product.outerWidth(true);
```